# Importing a submodule given a module object

Tags: python, dynamic, import

I am given a module as an object, and I need to import a submodule from it. Like this:

```
import logging
x = logging
```

Now I want to import `logging.handlers` using only `x` and not the name "logging". (This is because I am doing some dynamic imports and won't know the name of the module.)

How do I do this? If I do `import x.handlers` it fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
__import__('%s.handlers' % x.__name__)
```

Note that this will return a reference to `logging`, which you probably won't care about. It will create `x.handlers` though.

Comment: I'm trying to think why importing from a module object doesn't work, and it seems reasonable that it probably should. Is there a specific reason that you know of why it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in function `__import__`:
[http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#**import**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__)